# Implementing ImageViewTouch on Gallery

Tags: android, imageview, zooming, gallery

I have a code with a `ImageViewTouch` image that have pinch zoom, but i cant implement it on the gallery, i tried everything like setting in the `ImageAdapter`, it works but the `Gallery` wont scroll.

I think that another solution will be using a `ImageSwitcher`.

I ask if somebody have a code of a Gallery Implementing a `ImageView` extension with scroll enabled, or a `ImageSwitcher` with the Gallery scroll (No Animations).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I've found that works is to set an `OnTouchListener` on the Gallery itself, and then manually map the coordinates of the touch event to the underlying view with `getLocationOnScreen`.

Comment: ok, but how can i implement a OnTouchListener so the Gallery extends my ImageViewTouchBase??

Comment: Maybe try something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937313/android-basic-gesture-detection